# Does the standard basis only span Euclidean vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Does the standard basis only span Euclidean vector spaces?

I think I erroneously assumed that any $n$-dimensional vector space would have the $n$-dimensional standard basis, but I'm realizing that no linear combination of the n-dimensional standard basis would generate a polynomial of degree $n-1$, which is an n-dimensional vector space.

Comment: "Standard basis" is something that can only be talked about once you have fixed a vector space. Many vector spaces come equipped with a natural or obvious basis that you might call "standard" (e.g. $\{1, x, x^2, …, x^{n}\}$ for polynomials), but obviously different spaces have completely different bases.

Comment: @T.Bongers Thanks